# Display filename of an image in Picture cell

Tags: excel

I have an excel file where images are inserted into cells with [the "place in cell" function](https://insider.microsoft365.com/en-us/blog/insert-pictures-in-cells-in-excel), which was introduced in 2024. I.e. local images have been inserted with: `Insert > Pictures > Place in Cell > Picture from File...`

I need to know the filename that each local file had when it was inserted. How can I determine their filenames? Ideally I would like to display the filename in an adjacent cell, but any kind of way to display it would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that Excel keeps track of the filename, I believe it just gets the image out of the file.
In order to test this, I have created an empty Excel sheet and inserted a picture, using the feature you mentioned. The name of the file was "350450_Something.jpeg". Then I saved the Excel file.

Afterwards I unzipped the Excel file and searched for "350450" in the file, but I didn't find anything (WSL Linux `find` command):

```
find ./ -type f -exec grep "350450" {} /dev/null \;
```

If you really need this, I would advise you to write a macro, using a `FileDialog` (or an `OpenFileDialog`), and call the "Place in cell" Excel feature from your macro. That way, you will have full control of the filename.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Of course I'm disappointed that pictures in cells aren't that well considered by the developers at Microsoft, but I'm very happy about knowing that this is the case. How would I let Microsoft know about this? Where do I report bugs and request features?